# Rails using a nested path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

<%= project_attachment_path(attachment.project, attachment) %>

This outputs: `/projects/70/attachments/25`

<%= attachment.download_url %>

This outputs: `/attachments/25/original.jpg?1291407855`

What I want is: `/projects/70/attachments/25?original.jpg?1291407855`

I tried this: `<%= project_attachment_path(attachment.project, attachment.download_url) %>`

But that errors? is there a way to make the above work?

Thanks

UPDATING with Download_url method

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def download_url(style = nil, include_updated_timestamp = true)
    url = Paperclip::Interpolations.interpolate('/:class/:id/:style.:extension', attachment, style || attachment.default_style)
    include_updated_timestamp && attachment.updated_at ? [url, attachment.updated_at].compact.join(url.include?("?") ? "&" : "?") : url
  end
```

**ROUTES:**

```
resources :projects do
# Download Attachment
get "attachments/:id/:style.:format" => "attachments#download", :as => :attachment
end

resources :attachments do
 collection do
  get 'download', :as => :download
 end
end
```

**Rake Routes:**

```
project_attachment GET    /projects/:project_id/attachments/:id/:style.:format         {:action=>"download", :controller=>"attachments"}
```

Comment: Not enough detail to go on here. Is download_url a method you defined in your model, or are you using a plugin? The problem appears to be your routes, whatever 'download_url' is triggering doesn't realize that attachments are nested. Maybe if you describe it more we can help :)

Comment: @Andrew, sorry about that. I'm updating with the download_url method now.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does that give you all you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok: when you're using this...
    url = Paperclip::Interpolations.interpolate('/:class/:id/:style.:extension', attachment, style || attachment.default_style)

The `'/:class/:id/:style.:extension'` portion is what's creating your erroneous URL: /attachments/25/original.jpg?1291407855

I'm not sure *exactly* the best way to get the "projects/project_id" part into your url, but you need to do something like this:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  def download_url(style = nil, include_updated_timestamp = true)

    project_id = self.project.id.to_s

    attachment_url = Paperclip::Interpolations.interpolate('/:class/:id/:style.:extension', attachment, style || attachment.default_style)
    include_updated_timestamp && attachment.updated_at ? [url, attachment.updated_at].compact.join(url.include?("?") ? "&" : "?") : url

    url = 'projects/' + project_id + attachment_url
  end
```

There may be a more elegant way to do this, but I think this should get you on the right track. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can check all the available paths via:

```
rake routes
```

Comment: Thanks but I this I think is more related to using a method from the route.